# Would we prefer [dotemacs], [.emacs], [init.el] or [init-file]?

Tags: discussion, tags, tag-synonyms

Obviously, we only need a single tag referring to the init file. Currently, there are several questions using [dotemacs](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/dotemacs) (which is a fine name), and one using [init](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/init) (which is less fine, but it might be referring to "initialization" instead of init file, it's hard to say).

Other perfectly valid names for this tag would be [.emacs](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/.emacs), [init.el](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/init.el) or [init-file](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/init-file).

Do we have a preference either way?

Comment: There's also the possibility of using `.emacs`, but I'd assume many would find that weird.  Of course it could be made a synonym.

Comment: @paprika What's weird about `.emacs` (unless you only know `.emacs.d/init.el`)? Now `dotemacs`, that's a really weird name.

Comment: @Gilles: I guess the usage of the term `dotemacs` came from the renaming of the hidden `.emacs` files to make them accessible on the web.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

The tag should be **`init-file`**.  That is how Emacs itself refers to it, in [`(emacs) Init File`](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Init-File.html#Init-File).

That node explains what it is, and the fact that it can be `~/.emacs`, `~/.emacs.el`, or
`~/.emacs.d/init.el`.

(And for older Emacs versions the last of these is not a possibility. But it is still called the "**init file**", and the manual node is still `Init File`.)

Answer (score 10):

I strongly dislike the name [dotemacs](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/dotemacs). Is that pronounced dote-max? Names made of several words should have a separator between the words: [dot-emacs](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/dot-emacs) (like [on Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/dot-emacs)). It's strange to write it that way rather than [.emacs](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/.emacs).

While [.emacs](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/.emacs) has Emacs tradition for it, newer users might only know `.emacs.d/init.el`. Furthermore, `.emacs` has a risk of being used as a generic tag (“well, my question is about Emacs, so I'll use the tag that looks like ‘emacs’)”.

The [manual section](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Init-File.html#Init-File) about the topic is called “The Emacs Initialization File”, or “Init File” for short.

So I favor [initialization](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/initialization) or [init-file](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/init-file) (or [init-files](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/init-files) to include the system initialization files?), with [.emacs](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/.emacs) and [dot-emacs](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/dot-emacs) as synonyms.

Thinking about it some more, I fear that [.emacs](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/.emacs) or [dot-emacs](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/dot-emacs) will be abused as “I want to put something in my `.emacs` to solve my problem”. That's an argument against having a tag that means “user initialization file”. Questions that are genuinely about `.emacs (like [What should/shouldn't I do when keeping .emacs and .emacs.d in version control?](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/293/what-should-shouldnt-i-do-when-keeping-emacs-and-emacs-d-in-version-control) or ["Symbol's value as a variable is void: defun" when reloading .emacs?](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/375/symbols-value-as-a-variable-is-void-defun-when-reloading-emacs)) can use the more general tag [initialization](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/initialization).

Comment: [tag:initialization] could still refer to the actual init process as mentioned above.  [tag:init-file(s)] could work.

Comment: @JonathanLeech-Pepin Do we need to distinguish between the concepts? Are we looking for a tag specifically about the user init file or one that also covers the system init files?

Comment: I don't mean user vs system init files as such.  Questions about changing initial minibuffer message/*scratch* buffer mode, or about how initialization occurs (`emacs` vs `emacs -q` vs `emacs --batch` for example) are only indirectly about the init-file as opposed to about how emacs initializes itself.

Comment: I'm not sure a tag specifically about "initialization" would see a lot of usage not also tagged "init-file", but I definitely see a distinction. When we setup these synonyms, maybe it's worth leaving "initialization" alone.

Comment: For some reason I was under the impression that actual dots were not allowed in tag names. I updated the question to improve that.

Comment: @JonathanLeech-Pepin Thinking about it some more, I think [tag:initialization] is a superset of [tag:init-files] which is a superset [tag:.emacs], and I'm not convinced that we really need the narrower tags.

Comment: @Malabarba I do see a distinction between [tag:initialization] and [tag:init-files] and [tag:.emacs], but I'm not convinced that it needs to be reflected in the tags.

Answer (score 3):

I like **init-file**, it's generic and it's clear of what is referring to.

Answer (score 1):

Since this site is not only for GNU Emacs, using ".emacs" or "dotemacs" is simply inappropriate since XEmacs only supports it for compatibility purposes.

I definitely vote for the use of `init-file` in preference to all the others.  But I also agree with Gilles that there's a risk this will end up being abused since most questions are likely to be about configuration of Emacs, and hence relate to what to write in the init file.

Answer (score 0):

I would prefer [dotemacs](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/dotemacs) to the others.

It reflects both the `~/.emacs`,`~/.emacs.el` as well as the folder `~/.emacs.d/init.el` approach while [init](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/init) and [init-el](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/init-el) feel less precise for this purpose.

[init](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/init) could however be used to point to `init` related questions (e.g. [How to change default minibuffer message?](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/432/how-to-change-default-minibuffer-message)).  This can be solved either in Customize or through initialization file changes, yet deals specifically with emacs initialization.

---

#### Edit

Following the other answers I have to revise my opinion.

[dot-emacs](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/dot-emacs) or [.emacs](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/.emacs) (to avoid ambiguity for [dotemacs](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/dotemacs)) or [init-file](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/init-file) seem best to me.  Even though `.emacs` is deprecated for `.emacs.d\init.el` (or at least the latter is preferred) it is still part of the name for the init-file so could be applicable.

Other options still feel potentially ambiguous to me.

Comment: regardless of what we do for the init file, initialization related questions should (in the least) be tagged "initialization" not init, to avoid confusion with init files.

Comment: For some reason I was under the impression that actual dots were not allowed in tag names. I updated the question to improve that.