# Can someone define .emacs as a synonym of init-file?

Tags: discussion, tag-synonyms

[As previously discussed](https://emacs.meta.stackexchange.com/q/65/50),
I recently took the time to convert all [dotemacs](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/dotemacs) tags to
[init-file](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/init-file).

Now we have 2 questions tagged with [.emacs](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/.emacs).
Instead of retagging the questions I figured we should
[suggest this as a synonym](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/tags/init-file/synonyms)
of [init-file](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/init-file). I can’t do that because I don’t have enough points
on the tag.

[Could someone do that please?](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/tags/init-file/synonyms)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Done.

The synonym system [doesn't work the best for small sites](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/127459/does-the-tag-synonym-suggestion-system-work). However, once there are moderators installed, they will be able to create synonyms. Talking it out on meta, as you did here, is a good way to go.

Comment: That's good to know, thanks.