# Shall we abolish the [configuration] tag?

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags

The [configuration](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/configuration) tag is a bit of a mess right now. Click the button and see for yourself.

It seems to be used for essentially anything, and seeing the tag gives me no information on what the questionis about.

The most common use is something similar to "configuration files", but we already have [init-file](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/init-file) for that purpose (which is usually also used in these questions).

What should we do about it?

Edit: [configuration](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/configuration) is now a synonym for [init-file](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/init-file)

Comment: I agree! I am having so much trouble trying to create a tag-wiki for the tag.

Comment: Related: [tag:customize] (mentioned in [this earlier meta thread](http://meta.emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/47/tag-for-certain-kinds-of-visual-interface-customization). It's getting used as a generic tag as well, but we do need a tag for the Customization interface.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It seems like a [meta-tag](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/08/the-death-of-meta-tags/) to me; it doesn't look like it adds classification to any questions that are not further classified by other tags (such as one indicating *which* of the many potential features one is attempting to "configure").

I would vote for destroying it.

Answer (score 2):

By itself, it should not be a useless tag: some questions are about configuring emacs, other are about using emacs.

Even if we exclude questions about a specific configuration area, which could and should be tagged accordingly, remain some general configuration questions.

Examples:

- [How do I "group" hooks?](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/q/501/184)
- [Synchronize packages between different machines](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/q/408/184)
- [What should/shouldn't I do when keeping .emacs and .emacs.d in version control?](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/q/293/184)

Most of these general questions could replace [configuration](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/configuration) with the [much discussed](https://emacs.meta.stackexchange.com/q/65/184) [init-file](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/init-file) tag.

So the only usage of [configuration](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/configuration) that I can think of would be to make a difference between "configuration" questions, and "usage" questions (together with additional tags). Note that this distinction is itself a very thin line: most "usage" questions end up involving some variable to set or some defun to evaluate, and it is usually trivial to adapt such a "usage" answer into a "configuration" one, by adding the relevant bit of elisp to the init file.

So... yes, in my opinion, we don't really need that tag.