# Is the [init] tag useful?

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags

Currently, the [init](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/init) tag has two usages. One question is specifically about `--debug-init` and is also tagged with [init-file](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/init-file). The [other question](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/432/how-to-change-default-minibuffer-message) is asking about events that happen at startup. This seems like the more useful of the two possibilities. It seems like [init-file](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/init-file) could cover all instances of needing to use `--debug-init` since the issue is going to be due to some bug in the init-file.

If the [init] tag is useful, is that the best name for it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Based on [Would we prefer [dotemacs], [.emacs], [init.el] or [init-file]?](https://emacs.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/65/would-we-prefer-dotemacs-emacs-init-el-or-init-file) , [init](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/init) should be [init-file](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/init-file) when referring to anything related to startup configuration (including debugging).

The second question (regarding events at startup) probably still falls under [init-file](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/init-file) since `how do I change it` is handled under the `init-file` (however `what is being triggered` has to do with how Emacs handles initialization).

Perhaps to ensure clarity a [startup](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/startup) should be used/created to deal with how Emacs starts up (the entire process, not just the init-file)

Comment: I agree with this mostly except for the fact that  [tag:init-file]'s wiki page says "Do not use this because you think the answer will involve adding a snippet to your init file." It seems like you are suggesting an exception to that guideline. Maybe the wiki page should be clarified.

Comment: I'd almost be inclined to say tag as `startup` (or equivalent) when creating the question, and then could have `init-file` edited in based on answers since that is how to change the behaviour.

Comment: @b4hand the reasoning behind that phrase is that 90% of the answers tangentially involve the init file. Events at startup involve the init file in a more fundamental (non tangential) way. So I think they'd be OK.

Comment: @Malabarba that's a good point, and seems like a reasonable addendum to the wiki tag page.

Comment: @Malabarba @b4hand , I've added a few bullet points to the `init-file` tag description (not the excerpt) summarizing this.